# What is the proper way to modify classes contained in maps?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a map of classes. If I use an iterator to go through the map, I cannot modify the contents of the class, since they need to be const. Is there anyway that a person could iterate through a map (or other STL container using iterators) and call a function which modifies the content of each of the objects?

For instance:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    class stuff
    {
        public:
            void setFoo(int foo);
            int getFoo();
        private:
            int aFoo;
    };

    void stuff::setFoo(int foo)
    {
        this->aFoo = foo;
    }

    int stuff::getFoo()
    {
        return this->aFoo;
    }

    int main()
    {
        stuff myStuff;
        stuff myOtherStuff;

        myStuff.setFoo(10);
        myOtherStuff.setFoo(20);

        map<int, stuff> myMap;

        myMap.insert(pair<int,stuff>(0, myStuff));
        myMap.insert(pair<int,stuff>(5, myOtherStuff));


        map<int, stuff>::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();

        while (it != myMap.end())
        {
            it->second.setFoo(it->second.getFoo() * 5); //Expect myStuff.aFoo = 50 and myOtherStuff.aFoo = 100
            cout << it->first << " " << it->second.getFoo() << endl;
            it++;
        }
    }
```

This will not work because of the const limitations. What would be the proper way to get it to work as intended?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using a `const_iterator`, rather than simple `iterator`?

Comment: The proper way is to not use a const_iterator when you want to modify.

Comment: If using C++x11, then just do `for (auto &it : myMap) {it.second.setFoo(...);}`

Comment: While we're on the subject of `const`, `stuff::getFoo` should have a trailing `const` modifier, since it does not modify the object which it is called on. --- `int getFoo() const;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, good point! I am actually looking at someone else's code, and it just got me thinking-- I'm not too up to speed on the STL containers. It seemed like you always got back a const object. Using just a plain old iterator seems to be the way to go!

Answer (score 4):

Just use `map<int, stuff>::iterator` instead of `map<int, stuff>::const_iterator`